# Can someone give me an example of a Haskell function of the type (Int->Int)->Int

Tags: haskell

I have been asked to give an example of a function defined as (Int->Int)->Int in Haskell. No matter how simple.

Answer (score 5):

`(Int -> Int) -> Int` is a function of one argument. The type of the argument is `Int -> Int`, and the return type is `Int`

The argument has type `Int -> Int`, which means that it's also a function of one argument. This function's argument is of type `Int` and its return type is `Int`

The simplest example would be probably this:

```
f :: (Int -> Int) -> Int
f g = g 42
```

Answer (score 5):

As explained, `(Int -> Int) -> Int` is the type of a function producing an `Int` from another function, which in turns produces an `Int` from an `Int`.

How simple can such a function be?

Think about it:

- you want to generate an `Int`
- but the only argument you can use to do so is a function `Int -> Int`, ***for which you are not given an input!***
- So you either

  1. ignore that input function entirely and choose a result for *your* function, e.g. `6`

     ```hs
     f :: (Int -> Int) -> Int
     f _ = 6 -- _ means that I don't even bother
             -- giving a name to the argument,
             -- as I don't use it
     ```

     So `f` simply ignores its only argument and always gives you back `6`. Now look at [`const`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:const)'s description and examples. Oh, but that gives us a way to implement `f`,

     ```hs
     f :: (Int -> Int) -> Int
     f = const 6
     ```

     which also gives us the chance to choose a more appropriate name for `f`: `always6`.
  2. or choose a fixed argument for it (as suggested in the other answer), e.g. `6`

     ```hs
     f :: (Int -> Int) -> Int
     f g = g 6
     ```

     Here `f` takes `g` and applies it to 6, no matter what. A better name for this `f` function would be maybe `applyTo6`.